Grouping by a date in a timestamp depending on time zone
This is my query:
SELECT COUNT(*)
     , DATE(created_ts)
FROM users 
GROUP BY DATE(created_ts);

if the user selects a time range, such as
2024-12-17 00:00:00-2024-12-17 15:59:59
but a problem arises here. The user may be located in Shanghai, and the time sent to me by the front end is always UTC time.
The time the server received it was:
2024-12-16 16:00:00 - 2024-12-17 15:59:59
SELECT COUNT(*)
     , DATE(created_ts)
FROM users
WHERE NOT created_ts < '2024-12-16 16:00:00'
  AND created_ts <= '2024-12-17 15:59:59'
GROUP BY DATE(created_ts);

then the execution of this sql will generate groups No. 16-17.
this will cause COUNT(*) to be inaccurate. Please tell me how to deal with it.
I don't know what to do, I hope the query results are what the user wants, that's all

"the time the server received it was: 2024-12-16 16:00:00 - 2024-12-17 15:59:59" - so only the first value the user selected was modified, but the second one was kept as-is? That sounds unlikely. Plus, where and how is the user selecting this in the first place? Are we talking about a datetime-local input field in an HTML document, or - what exactly?

1) By default, timestamps use microsecond resolution. Shifting the upper bound one second down while making it inclusive will cause problems - just use 16:00 for both and make one exclusive with <, one exclusive with <=. Otherwise, there's a full second that won't belong to either range. 2) Make the column a timestampTZ and make the client send you a timestampTZ as well, to remove the ambiguity entirely. They are timezone-aware timestamps that cost exactly the same, while regular timestamp is a "picture of a clock" that's causing problems like the one you're facing.


Make the column a timestampTZ and make the client send you a timestampTZ as well, to remove the ambiguity entirely.
alter table users 
  alter column created_ts type timestampTZ;

They are time zone aware timestamps that cost exactly the same, while a regular timestamp is just a "picture of a clock" that's causing problems like the one you're facing. If your client is already sending you a UTC timestampTZ, you only need to make sure the column is altered and you should be fine.
By default, timestamps use microsecond resolution. Shifting the upper bound one second down while making it inclusive will cause problems - just use 16:00 for both and make one inclusive with >, one exclusive with <= (your first bound comparison was flipped by the way):
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT COUNT(*)
     , DATE(created_ts)
FROM users
WHERE NOT created_ts > '2024-12-16 16:00:00'
  AND created_ts <= '2024-12-17 16:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(created_ts);

Otherwise, there's a full second running from 15:59:59.000001 up to 15:59:59.999999 that won't belong to any range.
If your client is sending you a time zone unaware timestamp but you both agreed it's in UTC, you can use at time zone to apply the shift and make it time zone aware:
SELECT COUNT(*)
     , DATE(created_ts)
FROM users
WHERE NOT created_ts > '2024-12-16 16:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
  AND created_ts <= '2024-12-17 16:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
GROUP BY DATE(created_ts);

Making sure the session that runs this query opens with set TimeZone='UTC'; would have the same effect - comparing timestamptz to a timestamp makes Postgres prefer casting the latter to timestamptz rather than losing the time zone. And when it casts a timestamp to a timestamptz, it assumes it's in the time zone indicated by the current TimeZone setting.

